# Titanium USB Thermal Printer Driver

Tags: android, bluetooth, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am programming in Appcelerator Titanium now and i wanted to make a connection with thermal bluetooth printer MBT-58A(ESC/POS). The main problem is the sdk is only for android studio only. I need a help in connecting to USB with titanium. Is there any SDK or library out there to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For existing modules try [gitt.io](http://gitt.io/) and [Appcelerator Marketplace](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/home).

If you can't find any you have two options:

1. Wrap the SDK in a [Titanium Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide)
2. Use the [Hyperloop Beta](http://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55f74a9f421c44837717716b/Hyperloop-Module) to directly access JARs from JS.